# JDK1.8 and JDK1.7 anti-compiled after the difference

Tags: java, java-8

When I use JDK1.7 to compile this program and I decompile to see if the code is running as follows

```
 import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Demo
{

    public Demo()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

But when I use JDK1.8 to compile the same code and decompile to see the following code

```
 import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Demo
{
   public Demo()
    {
    }

    public static transient void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

You should be able to see more of a transient 。
Is this the difference between JDK1.8 and JDK1.7 compiler?Can you tell me why?
thank you very much in advance~

Comment: 1.) wat is the input code? 2.) which decompiler? `transient` is illegal for methods (how would that even work?). I guess it's a bug of the decompiler.

Comment: The decompiler is Xjad source code as follows:public class Demo
{

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  System.out.println("hello world");
 }
}

Comment: Common decompiler fault, it was attempting to manage a varag method modifier, but instead managed it as a transient field modifier. [`transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5) and [varag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6) are both represented as `0x0080`.

Comment: This is not JDK1.8 and JDK1.7 in the different compiler?

Comment: Can I try to use other anti-compilation tools that will be different?

Comment: @LPGAD It's called a [**decompiler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), not an anti-compiler.

Comment: As @Vince Emigh said, the appearance of `transient` indicates that the decompiler can’t handle varargs correctly, but this also implies that the original code didn’t look like you claim, as a varargs flag will only be set, if the method has been declared using varargs rather than an array. Since this hasn’t changed since Java 5, switching from Java 7 to Java 8 can’t make a difference, you simply failed to use the same class file when decompiling…